# How can I split this string?

Tags: ruby

I have this string:

```
a = "hy what are you doing [Zoho Reports] will you like? [Zoho Books] reply"
```

and I want to split it so the result is like this:

```
hy
what
are
you
doing
[Zoho Reports]
will
you
like?
[Zoho Books]
reply
```

How can I loop that string to achieve those results? I'm currently doing this:

```
a.split("")
```

but it splits up `"[Zoho Reports]"` into `"[Zoho"` and `"Reports]"`, which I don't want.

Comment: What's wrong with your approach?

Comment: @megas split string on what bases to achieve results?

Comment: because split on the base of space how i can achive "[Zoho Reports]" as one word

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not very pretty, but gets the job done:

```
a.scan(/(\S+)|(\[.+?\])/).map(&:compact).flatten
```

Later I noticed that the groups I used were not necessary at all and without them the solution could be simplified to:

```
a.scan(/\S+|\[.+?\]/)
```

Answer (score 6):

In this case, you should use `scan` instead of `split` because it is easier to characterize what you want rather than what you want to throw out.

Similar to Bozhidar's answer, but you don't need the complication.

```
a.scan(/\[.*?\]|\S+/)
```

Comment: Hmm, your regexp is missing a closing `/` and it doesn't seem to behave quite right even with it.

Comment: The mispositioned slash is because I edited it, and I think you tried it before my edit. See the change. I changed the order of the alternatives.